# sql syntax with arithmetic

Tags: sql, xml, coldfusion

I am getting a syntax error and I am not sure what I am doing wrong, any help would be much appreciated.

```
    INSERT INTO mashstp ( mid, name, time, temp, desc )
    VALUES ( '#mid#', '#mashstXML.mash_step.name.xmltext#',
    '( #mashstXML.mash_step.step_temp.xmltext# * 1.8 ) + 32 F',
    '#mashstXML.mash_step.description.xmltext#')
```

Comment: From the looks of it you are naming 5 columns to insert into but are only inserting 4 values.

Comment: While this one was easy to spot, in the future, please include the error message when you're asking for help fixing an error.

Comment: Are those your real column names? Because `DESC` is a reserved word in most databases. So not a good choice for a column name. `MID` and `TIME` are also reserved keywords in some databases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You name 5 columns, but only pass 4 values.

```
mid     '#mid#'
name    '#mashstXML.mash_step.name.xmltext#'
time
temp    '( #mashstXML.mash_step.step_temp.xmltext# * 1.8 ) + 32 F'
desc    '#mashstXML.mash_step.description.xmltext#'
```

I think it's missing `time`.

Answer (score 2):

It appears as if you've got your arithmetic inside the string you're inserting. Convert your text to a number and then do the math:

```
convert(float,'#mashstXML.mash_step.step_temp.xmltext#') * 1.8 + 32.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You name five columns to receive values but only supply four values.